# Dualband Routers with the same SSID?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I have recently purchased two Buffalo AirStation N600 Dualband routers and have set one up to be the main router and the other as a wireless access point.

Both are running open source DD-WRT firmware I was wondering if it was possible to set up all four radios to use the same SSID, and then my devices just roam between them picking up the strongest possible signal.

This is my current setup on one of the routers:
[image: Wifi Setup]

Are these likely to conflict at all?

Any advice on this would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Spiff, your answer on the other thread cleared everything up. I searched SU for ages before I posted this question, no idea why I couldn't find it. Upvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to set each antenna to use the same SSID, but make sure to use different channels on the different physical routers. All of the settings on the routers should be the same in regards to WPA/WPA2 and any keys.

Turn off DHCP on one of the routers and connect that one to a LAN port on the main router.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ConfiguringTwoWirelessRoutersWithOneSSIDNetworkNameAtHomeForFreeRoaming.aspx

Comment: Thanks, are there going to be any conflicts between the two routers? Or is this the recommended setup?

Comment: This configuration should pose no problems. The client should treat both routers as the same as long as they're broadcasting the same SSID and have the same security settings.